# Angular APP_INITIALIZER with Injector

Tags: angular

When using Angular `APP_INITIALIZER` with dependencies passed to the factory function - I generally see examples with the dependencies passed directly e.g. `deps: [ConfigurationService]`

But one can also provide the `Injector` as a `dep` and get the dependencies using that in the factory function

I was wondering is there a side effect or unforseen consequence to using `deps: [Injector]`, or is it equivalent to the `deps: [ConfigurationService]` approach?

```js
// AppModule
providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: configLoader,
    // Useful for multiple/conditional deps
    deps: [Injector],
    multi: true
}],
```

```js
export function configLoader(injector: Injector): () => Promise<Configuration> {
  return () => injector.get(ConfigurationService).loadConfiguration();
}
```

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigurationService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private features: FeatureService
  ) { }
```

**Update 1**: found an [article](https://i-topolev-vladimir.medium.com/3-powerful-tips-to-improve-angular-codebases-d355534701e9) with someone suggestion the same approach - so that's at least 2 people who think it's a good idea

**Update 2**: Angular v16+ now has a global `inject(...)` which can be used similar to my example above within the `useFactory` method - but no `deps` are needed

Comment: I never heard of problems because of this, but I see it as an antipattern of sorts. It's more elegant and more expected to see the actual dependencies of the function/class instead of passing the injector and have all the dependencies be hidden away.

Comment: why do you not inject the "ConfigurationService" instead the "Injector"?

Comment: @Eliseo I think Passing Injector as deps we can resolve multiple dependencies inside factory function without manually declaring any dependencies inside deps array

Comment: @Eliseo If you declare a service via `deps` directly it gets instantiated - but if your initializer function potentially needs multiple services conditionally based on particular responses, then `Injector` is a good approach from what I can tell